# How to change admin secure value and generate integration keys for api?

Tags: admin, magento2.3, https, command-line

I've developed a script which sets up my magento installations from scratch to production mode with ssl etc.

I have on tiny problem and that is, I am not sure which command to use in order to change the secure admin value from 0 to 1? The whole point of this script is to make the installation process easy, so I'm eliminating having to login to phpmyadmin or using mysql etc.

Changing URLs works for me from terminal by just using one single command on Bitnami, but the value is not changing as I am not sure how to from terminal. Any help here is appreciated.

Another question is, is there a way for me to generate integration keys from terminal?

It's all part of a big project where I'm letting clients deploy servers with scripts that runs the installation processes for them.

Many thanks for any help here!